# Photo downloading

Tags: photo

I have a digital Nikon Coolpix. No more Microsoft after a friend download Ubuntu. So far liking it as in security of past virus! Anyway; love posting photos on facebook and was able to do seamlessly with the microsoft program...however, no luck with the new Ubuntu. Found and printed out instructions - but nothing working. It does not "automatically detect when plugging in and offer to import photos automatically". Attmpted the F-Spot application. Opened the "Applications - then Graphics - but graphics drop screen did not show the "F-Spot Photo Manager, therefore no "file-Import". Help! Thank you :-)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What exact device is this concerned? Does the device offer you a bunch of connectivity options for USB? E.g. USB mass storage, PTP/MTP, etc. Please **edit** your question to provide a bit more information. Keep in mind that we don't have your hardware and we can't see your screen, so we rely on the specific information you provide in your question.

Answer (score 0):

What should work (almost) always, is taking out the memory card and putting it in a card reader. F-Spot should recognize that.

That said, I can't really give an answer because you haven't told how the camera is connected. (What the manual says will be useless anyway as that's written for Windows.)